# Why change in ArrayCollection's length doesn't invoke Setter on component using it as data source?

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding, arraycollection

I have a component where I expose the property 'questions' with the following code:

```
private var _questions:ArrayCollection;
private var questionsChanged:Boolean;

[Bindable("questionsChanged")]
public function get questions():ArrayCollection {
    return _questions;
}

public function set questions(value:ArrayCollection):void {
    if (_questions != value) {
        _questions = value;
        questionsChanged = true;
        invalidateProperties();
        dispatchEvent(new Event("questionsChanged"));
    }
}
```

In this component, I use commitProperties() to implement my logic.

I use Cairngorm and the 'questions' is in the model and hence it's defined as a source for data binding.

When the 'questions' ArrayCollection's size changes elsewhere in the application, it is not invoking the setter method in the component that is destination for the data binding.

Could someone help me understand why this is the case?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't the Bindable metadata tag syntax be `[Bindable(event="questionsChanged")]`?

Comment: And shouldn't Bindable be located before setter instead of getter.

Comment: @2DH, when binding to a setter/getter, the setter must dispatch the event.  The getter uses the Bindable metadata tag to dictate which event it will expect to instruct it to notify whatever is bound to it of the update.

Comment: Yep, you're right. At the Adobe examples it was put before setter in one of the examples and before getter in the other. That got me confused. Shame on me.

Comment: @2DH The getter and setter are seen as a "unit" by the Flex compiler, it doesn't matter which one the Bindable metadata tag is before.  You can have read only Bindable properties, for example, and in that case you only have a getter to put Bindable before.  @bedwyr I'm pretty sure that if no value is assigned (AKA event=) then the specified value goes to the default property of the event, which for Bindable is 'event', so the original code is not incorrect.  I find it more overt to use the full syntax.

Comment: @bedwyr One more thing.  The setter does not have to dispatch the bindable / change event, although that is the most common practice.  Anything can dispatch that event and trigger binding.  Using this approach, you can have bindable read only properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to show the code where you are changing the array collection.  But, this will fire the setter:

```
questions = somethingArrayCollection();
```

This will not:

```
questions.addItem(newQestion)
```

The questions variable is, basically, a pointer.  Changing the thing that the variable points to does not need the set event.

I suggest you look at the CollectionChangeEvent, which the ArrayCollection fires when items are added to and from that.  Listen to the event and perform your 'change' actions in the event handler.  ( or tie into the lifecycle and invalidate some flag and perform your changes in commitProperties() )